# Search structure with history (persistence)

Tags: c++, data-structures, persistent

I need a map-like data structure (in C++) for storing pairs (Key,T) with the following functionality:

- You can insert new elements (Key,T) into the current structure
- You can search for elements based on Key in the current structure
- You can make a "snapshot" of the current version of the structure
- You can switch to one of the versions of the structures which you took the snapshot of and continue all operations from there
- Completely remove one of the versions

What I don't need

- Element removal from the structure
- Merging of different versions of the structure into one
- Iteration over all (or some of) elements currently stored in the structure

In other words, you have some search structure that you can build up, but at any point you can jump in history, and expand the earlier/different version of the structure in a different way. Later on you may jump between those different versions.

In my project, Key and T are likely to be integers or pointer values, but not strings.

The primary objective is to reduce the time complexity; space consumption is secondary (but should be reasonable as well). To clarify, for me log(N)+log(S) (where N-number of elements, S-number of snapshots) would be enough, although faster is better :)

I have some rough idea how to implement it --- for example: being the structure a binary search tree, the insertion of a new element can clone the path from the root to the insertion location, while keeping the rest of the tree intact. Switching tree versions would be equivalent to picking a different version of the root node, for which some changes are simply not visible.

However, to make this custom tree efficient (e.g. self-balancing) it will require some additional effort and careful coding. Of course I can do it myself but perhaps there are already existing libraries to do exactly that?

Also, there is probably a proper name for this kind of data structure that I simply don't know, making my Google searches (or SO searches) total failures...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You never mentioned ordered keys; the inner structure could be a hash table for faster access.  Give each a pointer to its parent snapshot and do chained probes for linear time in snapshot count, but constant time in total item count.

Comment: To help in your search: *persistent* is the term used to qualify such data structures. It is usually implemented using reference counting under the hood.

Comment: Linear time in the snapshot count may be too slow. I would prefer something around log(N) or even completely hiding the snapshots

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is an immutable map. Functional (or functionally inspired) programming languages (such as Haskell or Scala) have immutable versions of most of the containers you'd find in the STL. Operations such as insertion/removal etc. then return a copy of the map (preserving the original) with the copy containing your requested modification. A lot of work has gone into designing the datastructures so that the copies are able to point to as much of the original datastructure as possible to reduce time and memory complexity of each operation.

You can find a lot more details in a book such as this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Purely-Functional-Structures-Chris-Okasaki/dp/0521663504.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to answer. I'll just add OCaml to the list of languages that provide such structures.

Comment: It's good to have hints but the OP asked for a library that supports this to avoid re-implementing it. I honestly do not know whether such library exist, so hints are good I guess, but this was not the core question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will definetely look into that book, perhaps it will allow me to better specify my needs and help my implementation... -IF- I decide to implement it myself.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks to you I found a pdf version of PhD thesis of Okasaki under the same title: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf

Comment: @CygnusX1: I had a good hunt for you for existing implementations, but none seemed to appear. There is [FC++](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~yannis/fc++/) which seems now retired, and never had a tree structure - but nothing else came to light. Glad you found the thesis!

Comment: Thank you for your time spent on searching it. I stumbled on FC++ link as well, here on SO, but it was dead. Note, it does not have to be a tree as long as it is in reasonable time complexity, something around log(N)+log(S) (where S is number of snapshots).

Answer (score 0):

While searching for some persistent search trees libraries I stumbled on this:

http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~dana/pbst/

While it does not have the exact same functionality as needed, it seems pretty close to it. I will investigate.

(posting here, as someone may find it useful as well)